# Accounts still there hours after deletion countdown completed

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I have 3 accounts that I am deleting - however, several hours after the 24 hour (+ grace period - end about 4-5 hours ago), the countdown completed, but disappeared and the accounts are still there.

I would rather not go through another 24 hours, and would like to have these accounts deleted (and yes, I have thought about it and this decision is not up for discussion).

Currently, the accounts are still there.  Could this please be seen to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been taken care of. The accounts you had scheduled for deletion were just a *tad* bit too awesome for the system to act on it automatically, and a human being needed to push a few buttons before it went through. I've done this, and the accounts are removed (or in the process of being removed, it's a queue).

Sorry about the delay! We normally act on these well before the countdown expires, if there's going to be a delay.

Comment: No apology necessary!  Thank you and the team for helping me out!  and especially for the `tad bit too awesome` - made my day!