# Change text for case when deletion process is waiting for SE employee approval

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts

1. [вчера эта учётная запись будет удалена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7896/15479).
2. ["5 часов назад эта учётная запись будет удалена"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9352/15479).

For high-rep users, as [we know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248200/260198), "human being needed to push a few buttons".

But the message didn't changed after 24-hour period has ended. Member see this:

> [image]

Message:

> This account is scheduled to be deleted 5 hours ago. To cancel deletion, click here.

Could you use different string for this case? Something like:

> This account deletion process is waiting for *****

**UPD:** it's not about translation. It's a global problem, because in case when the process is waiting SE employee approval, the text is just misleading even on EN sites.

Comment: Worth noting that this was recently changed: in the past, the notice just *disappeared entirely*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this needs actually changing. In the [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) it is explained account deletion can be held up by a ton of corner cases and all of them are described with the ultimate detail. Those that are to delete their account will  never care about those details.

If it needs better wording then maybe something like

> This account is scheduled to be deleted no earlier than 20th July, 2019 at 9:36 (5 hours ago). To cancel deletion, click here.

but that doesn't make the message any clearer in my opinion. I don't think it is needed to tailor this message based on which condition causes the account deletion to be stalled.

Comment: For this particular user deletion was postponed for more than 10 hours.

Comment: @Suvitruf so? It can be postponed for days. There is nothing in the process that prevents that from happening.

Comment: Yes. I've asked to change the text to something "The process is waiting approval" to be more clear.

Comment: It's *extremely confusing* for a user to see that "this account is scheduled to be deleted 2 days ago". Much better to say something like "this account was originally scheduled to be deleted [x] days ago. However, as you have a lot of activity, this deletion requires manual approval. If your account has not been deleted within [y] days of the original deletion date, please [contact SE]."

Comment: Also, a clarification: the hourly scheduled task is *not* the only thing that can hold up a deletion. The same type of message (a deletion time in the past) can also occur if the user has cast enough votes such that the SE team needs to manually process the deletion (and potentially preserve votes).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog do you really expect me to repeat the whole FAQ post here again?